# light blinking randomization

Tags: scripting, lighting, drivers

I have bunch of lights.
Id like to make them blink similar but slightly randomly

In machine language:
P - power - main parameter drawn in graph editor
X - random value multiplier
noise(time) or random(time)

I imagine create driver in power parameter of each light with formula:
P + (noise(time)*X)

is it possible to do so?
I couldn't make running even #random()

any idea how to create such a driver?
thanks

Edit:
[image: random() or noise.random() is giving error]
[image: Expression is working without random]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Your driver expression should be `P + noise.random()*X`, and the noise.random function will provide a random value between 0-1 (different for each of your lamps).

Comment: Thanks, but my driver doesn't accept any of this scripts. I have allowed scripts but formula : **prop * noise.random()**   gives me 0

Comment: I've tried this in Blender 2.93.1 - this might be supported only on recent versions. And perhaps your prop is the cause of your problem, because if it didn't recognize the `noise.random()` bit you'd get an error. Try removing the prop and see if you get a random value.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the driver editor for this driver?

Comment: @TLousky yes it looks like it doesn't recognize random

Comment: here is blend file plane should drive the light
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=g23dvR8l" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/g23dvR8l/)

Comment: @TLousky in Blender 2.92.0 it works thanks for pointing me

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, that gives each light its own values for P and X, as well as for the Blink rate.  This gives maximum flexibility.

1. Add a light to the scene.  I picked a point light, but this approach will work for any.
2. Go the the Properties Editor, Object Data Properties Panel, Custom Properties drop down and add 3 new custom properties:

   - blink rate
   - power
   - X
     [image: New custom properties]
3. Edit each property and give it reasonable maximum and minimum values.
4. Pick one of the properties, hover over it, right click and select *Copy as New Driver*.  I picked power as a starting point, because the driver will be added to the Power setting of the light.
5. Hover over the Light's *Power* input field, right click and select *paste driver*.
6. Hover over the Light's *Power* input, right click and select *edit driver*
7. Change the Driver settings from *averaged value* to *Scripted* expression.
8. Add a new variable.  Set the *Prop* field to *light* and the name of your light object.  Set the name to whatever you called your X property. Set the bracketed name to the same thing.
9. Do the above for the blink field.  Your driver editor window should now look more or less like this, except with whatever names you picked for your properties.

   [image: Driver window]
10. Set the driver expression to something like this: `(power + noise.random() * x) * (frame % blink)`.  Again you have to use the names you gave your custom properties.
11. Click *Update Dependencies.*

Now when you copy your light you will also copy the custom properties and the driver.  Set the values of the fields appropriately to the blink rate, power setting, and variability you want.

The downside to this approach comes when you want the lamps to use the same settings, because you have to change each independently.  You can add similar custom properties to the scene and drive each of these custom properties from those, giving you a single point of control.

### About Driver Expressions

The Blender manual has a section on [Driver Expressions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#expressions) that explains in greater detail what is allowed, and I recommend reading the whole thing if you want to work with scripted expressions in drivers.

The upshot is that Blender recognizes a *subset* of Python legal expressions, You can create variables in the driver editor that reference properties or custom properties.  You can the use these variables in the expressions you create, but you must have a valid entry for the variable and you must refer to it in the expression by the name you gave it when you created the variable.

Comment: Problem is When I type expression 'x + random()' it say error: invalid Python expression. x + p works perfectly, Thanks

Comment: If i write for example `p+sin(2)` expression works well

Comment: you need `noise.` in front of `random` like this: `x + noise.random()`  `random` is a function from the `noise` set of functions, so you have to tell Python and Blender where to find it.

Comment: also `x + noise.random()` is invalid expression

Comment: @barberik I'm looking at your blend file.  `p + noise.random()` works fine, but when I try to edit the driver, or the properties on the plane, bizarre things happen.  I think you've hit a bug.  I'll look at it some more and see if I can figure out what to do.

Comment: I was using Blender 3, now i have opened it in Blender 2.92.0 and it looks like everything is working fine.

Comment: Great!  I guess you've run into a blender 3.0 bug.